# Sorted String with input characters pattern

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have the methode sortString, that have to sort characters in the string with pattern that i add.
**For example:**

if the **pattern** : List patter= Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z') and the **inputString is "bbacrrt"**
*sortString* have to return **"abbcrrt**" symbols that doesn't included in pattern have to add in the end of return string, order of this symbols doesn't metter.

In ideal way difficulty should be **O(n)**.

```
 private static String sortString(String inputString, List<Character> pattern) {
    List<Character> inputlist = convert(inputString); // method convert create List<Character> from String
    List<Character> returnedList = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(inputlist.size(), ' '));
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    boolean isAdded = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.size(); i++) {
        map.put(pattern.get(i), i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < inputlist.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pattern.size(); j++) {
            if (inputlist.get(i) == pattern.get(j)) {
                if (returnedList.get(map.get(pattern.get(j))) == pattern.get(j)) {
                    returnedList.add(map.get(pattern.get(j)), inputlist.get(i));
                } else {
                    if (map.get(pattern.get(j)) - 1 < 0) {
                        returnedList.add(map.get(pattern.get(j)), inputlist.get(i));
                    } else {
                        returnedList.add(map.get(pattern.get(j)) + 1, inputlist.get(i));
                    }
                }
                isAdded = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isAdded) {
            returnedList.add(inputlist.get(i));
        }
        isAdded = false;
    }
    return returnedList.toString();
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: "Could you help me?" isn't a specific enough question. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, does this code work? If not, what result do you get that differs from what you expect? Is the issue just that it is not O(n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that will help to someone
**This is my Solition:**

```
 private static String sortString(String input, List<Character> alphabet) {
    List<Character> inputlist = convert(input);    // method convert return List<Character> from String
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> returnedMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, String> orderedMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<List<String>> listWithSortedValues = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isAdded = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.size(); i++) {
        returnedMap.put(alphabet.get(i).toString(), new ArrayList<>());
        orderedMap.put(i ,alphabet.get(i).toString());
    }
    returnedMap.put("undefined", new ArrayList<>()); //better create CONSTANT private final static String UNDEFINED_PART = "undefined";
    orderedMap.put(alphabet.size(), "undefined");

    for (int i = 0; i < inputlist.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.size(); j++) {
            if (inputlist.get(i) == alphabet.get(j)) {
                ArrayList<String> strings = returnedMap.get(inputlist.get(i).toString());
                strings.add(alphabet.get(j).toString());
                returnedMap.put(alphabet.get(j).toString(), strings);
                isAdded = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isAdded) {
            ArrayList<String> unsortedValues = returnedMap.get("undefined");
            unsortedValues.add(inputlist.get(i).toString());
            returnedMap.put("undefined", unsortedValues);
        }
        isAdded = false;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < orderedMap.size(); i++) {
        String keyWithValueFromOrderedMap = orderedMap.get(i);
        listWithSortedValues.add(returnedMap.get(keyWithValueFromOrderedMap));
    }

    List<String> returnedList = listWithSortedValues.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return converterListToString(returnedList); //method converterListToString returned String from List<String>
```

Answer (score 2):

My initial thought was to use a `HashMap<String, ArrayList>` to store the `returnList`. Use the `String` part of the `HashMap` to store each character of the pattern and `ArrayList` to store each character of the `inputList` as you walked through that string.

When you want the final output, loop through the `HashMap` using the pattern as the index.

Answer (score 1):

When sorting characters, it's usually a counting sort.  Then use a boolean array to mark the characters in the pattern.  When you build the string, use the boolean array to check if the character should be append in the sort section or the unsorted section.  Use the count array to append the number of characters to the string.

This is an O(n) solution.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> pat = Arrays.asList('a', 'c',  'z');
        String s  = "atttbbacrrt";
        System.out.println(sort(pattern, input));
    }
    
    static String sort(List<Character> pat, String s) {
       boolean[] mustHave = new boolean[26];
       int[]     count    = new int[26];
       for(char c: pat) mustHave[c-'a'] = true;
       for(char c: s.toCharArray()) count[c-'a']++;
       
       StringBuilder sorted    = new StringBuilder();
       StringBuilder unsorted  = new StringBuilder();
       for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
          StringBuilder sb = mustHave[i] ? sorted : unsorted;
          for(int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++) sb.append((char)('a'+i));
       }
       return sorted.toString() + unsorted.toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aacbbrrtttt
```